# Mean and median by groups in within columns in R

Tags: r, mean, median

my data:

```
   id age gender school score      course group wage
1   1  18      0      0  3.63     Nursing     1 2.80
2   2  21      0      0 18.77 Engineering     2 5.00
3   3  20      1      1 21.76     Economy     4 4.50
4   4  19      1      2 12.57     Medical     1 6.00
5   5  20      1      2 20.69 Mathematics     2 1.80
6   6  20      1      2 13.94     Economy     4 4.50
7   7  23      0      1  1.25   Languages     5 2.10
8   8  18      1      1 13.07  Literature     5 2.30
9   9  18      0      1 12.94    Phiysics     2 2.00
10 10  19      0      1 12.63     Biology     1 2.50
11 11  22      0      0 13.01         Law     6 3.80
12 12  20      0      0 14.38    Phiysics     2 2.00
13 13  18      1      2 21.90 Engineering     2 5.00
14 14  19      0      1 15.13         Law     6 3.80
15 15  18      1      0  5.76  Journalism     6 2.75
16 16  18      0      2 11.88   Languages     5 2.10
17 17  25      1      0 12.51  Accounting     4 3.90
18 18  27      0      1 17.69  Accounting     4 3.90
19 19  18      1      1  4.64     Medical     1 6.00
20 20  18      1      2  5.77  Journalism     6 2.75

df <- structure(list(id = 1:20, age = c(18L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 
23L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 22L, 20L, 18L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 25L, 27L, 18L, 
18L), gender = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), school = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L
), score = c(3.63, 18.77, 21.76, 12.57, 20.69, 13.94, 1.25, 13.07, 
12.94, 12.63, 13.01, 14.38, 21.9, 15.13, 5.76, 11.88, 12.51, 
17.69, 4.64, 5.77), course = c("Nursing", "Engineering", "Economy", 
"Medical", "Mathematics", "Economy", "Languages", "Literature", 
"Phiysics", "Biology", "Law", "Phiysics", "Engineering", "Law", 
"Journalism", "Languages", "Accounting", "Accounting", "Medical", 
"Journalism"), group = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 
1L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 6L), wage = c(2.8, 5, 
4.5, 6, 1.8, 4.5, 2.1, 2.3, 2, 2.5, 3.8, 2, 5, 3.8, 2.75, 2.1, 
3.9, 3.9, 6, 2.75)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8tNJ.png)

How can I calculate mean and median using group data within columns and create a new column with that information for each row using R?

I want each row ( 'id )  contains information about mean and median for the respective group of the candidate.

I need a R code to count and calculate the mean and median using the candidate's performance (score) information within the group.

The goal is:

according to the overall performance within the group, mean and median score of each group, comparatively, a candidate can be = 'weak', 'competitive' or 'top'. (1,2,3).

I have a df with more than 50.000 row and 51 distincts courses. I wouldn't like have to calculate group by group manually, the way that I know the R code...

The way that I know to calculate mean and median by columns in R doesn't work to what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you need something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(mean_score = mean(score, na.rm = TRUE),
         median_score = median(score, na.rm = TRUE),
         candidate = case_when(score >= mean_score & score >= median_score ~ "top",
                               score >= mean_score & score < median_score ~ "competitive",
                               TRUE ~ "weak"), .by=group)
```

output:

```
  id age gender school score      course group wage mean_score median_score candidate
1   1  18      0      0  3.63     Nursing     1 2.80   8.367500        8.605      weak
2   2  21      0      0 18.77 Engineering     2 5.00  17.736000       18.770       top
3   3  20      1      1 21.76     Economy     4 4.50  16.475000       15.815       top
4   4  19      1      2 12.57     Medical     1 6.00   8.367500        8.605       top
5   5  20      1      2 20.69 Mathematics     2 1.80  17.736000       18.770       top
6   6  20      1      2 13.94     Economy     4 4.50  16.475000       15.815      weak
7   7  23      0      1  1.25   Languages     5 2.10   8.733333       11.880      weak
8   8  18      1      1 13.07  Literature     5 2.30   8.733333       11.880       top
9   9  18      0      1 12.94    Phiysics     2 2.00  17.736000       18.770      weak
10 10  19      0      1 12.63     Biology     1 2.50   8.367500        8.605       top
11 11  22      0      0 13.01         Law     6 3.80   9.917500        9.390       top
12 12  20      0      0 14.38    Phiysics     2 2.00  17.736000       18.770      weak
13 13  18      1      2 21.90 Engineering     2 5.00  17.736000       18.770       top
14 14  19      0      1 15.13         Law     6 3.80   9.917500        9.390       top
15 15  18      1      0  5.76  Journalism     6 2.75   9.917500        9.390      weak
16 16  18      0      2 11.88   Languages     5 2.10   8.733333       11.880       top
17 17  25      1      0 12.51  Accounting     4 3.90  16.475000       15.815      weak
18 18  27      0      1 17.69  Accounting     4 3.90  16.475000       15.815       top
19 19  18      1      1  4.64     Medical     1 6.00   8.367500        8.605      weak
20 20  18      1      2  5.77  Journalism     6 2.75   9.917500        9.390      weak
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:20, age = c(18L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 
23L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 22L, 20L, 18L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 25L, 27L, 18L, 
18L), gender = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), school = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L
), score = c(3.63, 18.77, 21.76, 12.57, 20.69, 13.94, 1.25, 13.07, 
12.94, 12.63, 13.01, 14.38, 21.9, 15.13, 5.76, 11.88, 12.51, 
17.69, 4.64, 5.77), course = c("Nursing", "Engineering", "Economy", 
"Medical", "Mathematics", "Economy", "Languages", "Literature", 
"Phiysics", "Biology", "Law", "Phiysics", "Engineering", "Law", 
"Journalism", "Languages", "Accounting", "Accounting", "Medical", 
"Journalism"), group = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 
1L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 6L), wage = c(2.8, 5, 
4.5, 6, 1.8, 4.5, 2.1, 2.3, 2, 2.5, 3.8, 2, 5, 3.8, 2.75, 2.1, 
3.9, 3.9, 6, 2.75)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Comment: If I want a mean for wage by courses  but I have to use a var weight  (because is a df from sample, each individual has a weight and I want to expand to population total), would be like this?

 df %>% 
  mutate(mean_score = mean(score * WEIGHT, na.rm = TRUE),
         median_score = median(score * WEIGHT, na.rm = TRUE),
         candidate = case_when(score >= mean_score & score >= 
          median_score ~ "top",
          score >= mean_score & score < median_score ~ "intermediate",
                               TRUE ~ "low"), .by=COURSE)

Comment: If I want a mean for wage by courses  but I have to use a var weight  (because is a df from sample, each individual has a weight and I want to expand to population total), would be like this?

Comment: df %>% 
  mutate(mean_score = mean(score * WEIGHT, na.rm = TRUE),
         median_score = median(score * WEIGHT, na.rm = TRUE),
         candidate = case_when(score >= mean_score & score >= 
          median_score ~ "top",
          score >= mean_score & score < median_score ~ "intermediate",
                               TRUE ~ "low"), .by=COURSE)